# Design LED light system, Lumen low

Tags: power-supply, current-source, led-strip, led-driver, led-matrix

I want to design a 4-way lighting system using LEDs. This is what I have so far.

LED driver: https://www.ledsupply.com/led-drivers/buckblock-dc-led-driver

LED: https://www.ledsupply.com/leds/cree-xlamp-xp-l-high-density-led-star

one way will have, one series line (9 LED's) with one LED driver.

Constant current = 2100mA
Total forward voltage = 9 * 3.1V = 28V
Flux at 2100mA =~ 800 lm for cool white.
Total flux/side = 9 * 800 lm = 7200 lm
Total flux = 4 * 7200lm = 28800 lm
My questions:

So with 4 LED drivers, 4 of 9 series LED strips, 1 battery pack of 36V, I should be able to power this system right?

Also, could somebody confirm my lumen calculations. It's my first time dealing with multiple LEDs.

Is there another efficient way to implement this? This is the highest current output driver I could find. If the is one that can output 9A, one driver can power all these 9 strip led's in parallel by itself.

[image]

Comment: Please draw a schematic or block diagram of what you are proposing.

Comment: All sounds ok. Note that Vin will need to be > about 60 V. If you use a single PSU to power the drivers you'll need around 300 Watts at say 60 V.

Comment: I didn't check the led l/W but it sounds about right.

Comment: Power at each LED is 6.5W, max power LED rated for is 10W. Why should Vin be >60V. I'm gonna connect 4 9-LED stips in parallel. wouldn't 36V be more than enough?